# Statistically finding performance differences

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, performance-testing

I am generating load on a server, and collecting performance metrics, every 10 seconds I save some data (IO util, CPU util, etc).

I make a change to the code and run another load test and collect metrics.

I have a ton of metrics so I'm looking for two things:

- Which metrics have changed the most
- Of those metrics that changed, how much did they change?

For the first task, I'm currently running a Pearson correlation and between the two runs and sorting by LOWEST correlation for each metric.

For the second task, I'm passing the metrics with the lowest correlation to a function where I just compare each runs average performance and subtract i.e. `sum(list_of_samples) / len(list_of_samples) - sum(list_of_samples2) / len(list_of_samples2)`

Unfortunately, I'm not getting good data which I suspect is due to:

- The data is somewhat noisy
- The load test will vary load to not overwhelm the server (increasing at different rates)

Does anybody know how I can approach this better, or some improvements I can make? I'm currently writing in Python but I can switch languages if there is some magic library that does this.

Comment: sounds like making a column of the difference and finding the MAX(s) would provide both things you're looking for.

Comment: What would be a good way to factor how hard I was stressing the machine? I also collect metrics on value between 0 and 100 that denotes stress. Just multiply by said number before finding the max?

Comment: if that 0-100 number helps your understanding of the data, then make a new number by multiplying the difference by the load, sort the spreadsheet / array of objects by that new number field, and then you'll have the real values, a load-balanced diff rank, raw diff, and load % for each snapshot. you can sort by other "columns" to get other stats.

Comment: What kind of load do you apply during the load test? Is it constant or raises linearly?

Comment: It relies on a feedback system. If the server starts denying requests, the load increment is decreased or may even become negative. The load will always change a constant number of times per run, however.

Answer (score 1):

That's how we do it.

The first test is to estimate maximum throughput. To do that, you just start one instance of load generator (one thread, for example), that sends requests to the server one-by-one without any pauses. Then start adding one more instance every minute. After a while, your throughput (processed requests per second) stops growing and may even fall down slightly because of concurrency issues. That's the maximum throughput for this test. You may use it to compare multiple tests when you changing your code. You also may find some interesting bottlenecks while your server is under maximum load.

The second test is to estimate response times. Select a level of load that is about 50-80% from maximum throughput you found in previous test. Generate *constant* load for about 10-15 minutes (depends on system, maybe in your case you'll have to warm up before the actual test). Collect response times and resources usage. Then you can compare different statistics from what you collected. For response times it may be a 99-th or 95-th [percentile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) and average load for cpu and disk.